# Text Field not showing when using list_editable on django admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I am using django-1.7 for my project. I am trying to use the `list_editable` option of the Django admin to edit one field of multiple objects at once. Here is my code:

```
class CustomForm(forms.ModelForm):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=100, required=False)

class CustomAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = CustomForm
    change_form = CustomForm
    list_display = ('status', )
    list_editable = ('status',)  

admin.site.register(Custom, CustmAdmin)
```

I am only able to see a save button on the list view page of this model. I can't find any text field for the `status` to enter text to update it on various objects of this model.

Any help would be appreciated

[image]

Comment: As an aside, I don't think you need to specify `change_form`. It is not a documented attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you only have one item in `list_display`, and Django is using that item to link to the change view for that item.

You can either add another field to the beginning of `list_display`, and then Django will automatically link that field.

```
class CustomAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('other_field', 'status')
    list_editable = ('status',)
```

Or you can set [`list_display_links`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display_links) to make a different field linkable. You can also do `list_display_links = None`, but then you won't be able to click through to edit the item.

Comment: Great, Thanks, It works, but couldn't get it from django documentation.

Comment: I think the checks in the Django admin could be improved, to catch your issue and show a warning. I opened a ticket [26229](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/26229#comment:1).

Comment: The ticket has now been fixed. The Django checks will detect the problem in your example and show an error in Django 1.10+.